# phyloseq: Discrepancies in otu counts before and after using tax_glom

Tags: r, phyloseq

Maybe I missed something in how tax_glom works but as I did not find any info here nor elsewhere on the web, maybe someone here can help.
I do not provide data but I can on request. Here is the code highlighting the issue I have

```
colSums(CYANO%>%otu_table())

CYANO_gen <- CYANO %>%
  tax_glom(taxrank = "Genus")
colSums(CYANO_gen%>%otu_table())
```

CYANO is a phyloseq object that I wanted to agglomerate at the Genus rank but I noticed that a sample (named 100) was not present in a dataviz. This led me to check where the issue happened. 7 samples out of 54 present discrepancies as shown in the last line of the attached image, weird isn't it?

[Results given by the code above and 2 additional lines which highlight the importance of discrepancies and the fact that this is not always the case](https://i.stack.imgur.com/13lpE.png)

Thank, Guillaume

Comment: Checking other datasets and having the same issues, I found the reason for the discrepancies which lays in the  bad_empty which has to be set to FALSE in tax_glom `tax_glom(taxrank = "Genus", bad_empty=F)`

Answer (score 0):

The `NArm` term in the `tax_glom` function is, by default, set as TRUE. To avoid losing observations with NA cells you need to set the `NArm = FALSE`.
Cheers